# Database design- Should seperate entities stored in different database?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, data-modeling, rdbms

currently I designing relational database model for simple IoT application. The entities I have are:

Device data: temperature, error, configuration table..

Device master data: device manufacturer, model, serial number information table..

User master data: owner of device, owner personal info..

For security and privacy purpose, my approach is store these 3 entities into 3 difference database (same database engine, different host) mainly to seperate user data from others entity. However, I will provided API gateway for my user to retrieve specific data. It may require cross database link to join these 3 entities for query purpose.

Is this belonging to best practice of database design model? Any advice?

Comment: Separating this into different hosts only makes sense if those hosts are on physically separate properties and there are legal or other reasons for such separation. Otherwise, it should be perfectly fine to store them within the same database and manage access permissions with the database's permission system and separate user accounts, if that is even necessary at all.

Comment: It may make sens for performance purpose rather than for security one (parallel querying). Are you in really big data volume (1+ Petabyte)?